# Is it good to use jSon vs DB for static data

Tags: json, database, image, file, system

I am using **c# windows form application**.I need to store some Images later on will use them in application.

Is it good to store images locally on drive and use **jSon** file with key,value,path.
or to store the images in **Database**.

Comment: can you please be more specific how do you intend to store them using a JSON

Comment: Why do you want to store an image in a JSON file? And which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Dear, actually I am working on Image processing OpenCV. That detect images on real-time and show it's value like:
Car, Bike, Ship etc
Thank you

Comment: How many images do you need to store? How many users will access them? How long will the data be stored? ...

Comment: this is a single user system images approximately 100 images for a long period it stores